# What mechanisms tell temperate trees when to drop leaves?

Tags: botany, metabolism, phenology

I've been looking around and cannot find a definite answer on what it is that tells trees to change their metabolism and drop leaves. I see that such activity is called [Deciduous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deciduous).

What interests me **are the specific mechanisms by which a tree knows that it's time to drop leaves**. Is it photoperiod shortening (day duration?) Is it temperature changing metabolism? Is it build up of some toxic compound?

Thank you for your input!

Comment: For answers, also see the duplicate [what is the mechanism behind plants losing their leaves?](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/31371/what-is-the-mechanism-behind-plants-losing-their-leaves).

Comment: FYI: "Deciduous" is not the activity itself of losing leaves.  (The activity is called "abscission.")  Rather, "deciduous" is an adjective that describes the types of trees that display abscission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good USDA link:

http://www.usna.usda.gov/PhotoGallery/FallFoliage/ScienceFallColor.html

It would appear that the shortening days are a main trigger, and there are other factors. I did a basic search using Google for "what triggers leaf fall in deciduous trees?", since I always thought temperature and changing seasons were major triggers and wanted to double check.